# How to get `RuntimeOrigin::root()`'s account id?

Tags: assets, root

I want to set the root account as the asset's owner in `pallet-assets`'s genesis config.

How to get `RuntimeOrigin::root()`'s account id?

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get RuntimeOrigin::root()'s account id?

The `RuntimeOrigin::Root` has no account id.

If you use `pallet-sudo`, there you configure an account id that is allowed to get sudo rights. You could use this account id as your asset owner.